# header() function in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a site with authentication using PHP sessions with a database. i dont know how to solve this.

`header("location:singleprod.php?product_id=$row['product_id']");`

the header is not working. The error shown is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Any help please.... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What appears in the browser after re-direction?

Comment: quick solution will be to add ob_start at the first line of the file just next to the php opening tag like <?php ob_start(); Didn't see your error message when I posted my comment.

Comment: its not getting redirected. The error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) is shown

Comment: The code is basically some thing like this.. if (!$result_insert_user) {
  echo 'Query Failed ';
  } else {
  header("location:single_prod.php?product_id=$row['product_id']");
  }

Comment: I think you need to post few lines of code above this condition so that it will be useful to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("Location: singleprod.php?product_id=".$row['product_id']);
```

use this instead

Comment: thank you so much. it worked.

Comment: no problem :) glad could help @AyantiGoswami

Comment: @AyantiGoswami dont forget to verify the ans

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
header("location:singleprod.php?product_id=".$row['product_id'].");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$result_insert_user){
    echo 'Query Failed ';
}else{
    header("location:single_prod.php?product_id=".$row['product_‌​id']);
}
```

Use above code.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a space after colon (:)

```
header("Location: singleprod.php?product_id=$row['product_id']");
```

Update: why the downvote? I didn't type full url because I answered using mobile.